# Android AlertDialog align buttons to bottom not working

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an Android `AlertDialog` with some info and Neutral and Positive buttons.

I set the size of the `AlertDialog` with the following line, which gives it the correct height that i want:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder alert = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
alert.setView(wifiResultView);
// stuff
alertDialog = alert.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

However, the buttons align with the end of the data in the dialog and i can't for the life of me figure out how to get them to stick to the bottom. Does anybody have any idea? I would greatly appreciate it.

I want the buttons to stick to the bottom of the window, with space between the data and the buttons (not with space below the buttons like in the picture).

I'm using Android 11 (Samsung Galaxy S10e)

[image]

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `AlertDialog`. To align buttons to bottom you have to change also the height of `AlertDialogLayout` which is the alert container to `MATCH_PARENT`. Unfortunately there is no currently a public API to retrieve the  `AlertDialogLayout` from `AlertDialog`, so below i will describe two possible solutions to retrieve it from `AlertDialog` and change its height.

1.Find the AlertDialogLayout directly from the PositiveButton:

```
Button btn = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
AlertDialogLayout alertDialogLayout = (AlertDialogLayout) btn.getParent().getParent().getParent();
alertDialogLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

2.Find the AlertDialogLayout in a recurring way starting from the  PositiveButton root view:

```
Button btn = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
View rootView = btn.getRootView();
findAlertDialogLayoutAndSetParams(rootView);
```

where `findAlertDialogLayoutAndSetParams(View view)` is a helper function and it reccurres until it finds the AlertDialogLayout:

```
private void findAlertDialogLayoutAndSetParams(View view){

    if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if(childView instanceof ViewGroup) {
                if(childView instanceof AlertDialogLayout){
                    AlertDialogLayout alertDialogLayout = (AlertDialogLayout)childView;
                    alertDialogLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                }
                else {
                    findAlertDialogLayoutAndSetParams(childView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Complete Example:**

```
//get your custom view
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View wifiResultView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_view_layout, null, false);

//create the MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder alert = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", null);
alert.setView(wifiResultView);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

//stick the buttons to the bottom by setting the height of AlertDialogLayout to MATCH_PARENT
//1st option - get the AlertDialogLayout directly from the positive button
Button btn = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
AlertDialogLayout alertDialogLayout = (AlertDialogLayout) btn.getParent().getParent().getParent();
alertDialogLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//2nd option - find AlertDialogLayout in a recurring way starting from the positive button root view
//Button btn = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
//View rootView = btn.getRootView();
//findAlertDialogLayoutAndSetParams(rootView);
```

**Results before/after:**

[image: buttons_before]
[image: buttons_after]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code and it work fine :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("test title");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("unfreeze", (dialog, which) -> {
        // do some things
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("ok", (dialog, which) -> {
        // do some things
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow()
            .setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    alertDialog.show();
```

can you please share more details of your code of AlertDialog and your device Android version, also try to test in anther phone.

**Edit**

You can put `Space` in the end of the `wifiResultView` :

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

than change `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` to `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

your code will be like this :

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I have edited the post to include the information you requested.
By the way, when i build the dialog like you do in your example, the height of the dialog is not like i want it but rather the height wraps the content.

Comment: Why you don't put your `Buttons` inside  `wifiResultView `

Comment: I tried that but it does not put the buttons at the bottom either, it puts them above where the buttons on the dialog would be.

Comment: See edit of my answer I hope that works